# Why my indicator is not working when loading web view?

Tags: ios, swift

Using swift3 with Xcode8

Below is mu view controller.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var YahooWebview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
        YahooWebview.delegate = self
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let YURL = URL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")
        let YURLRequest = URLRequest(url: YURL!)
        YahooWebview.loadRequest(YURLRequest)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(YahooWebview: UIWebView) {
        print("show indicator")
        activity.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(YahooWebview: UIWebView) {
        activity.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

From my log in Xcode, it print "show indicator" then stop and then show something like the picture below.

[image]

Seems like something wrong with code below

```
activity.startAnimating()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: whats your `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` is `White` or else

Comment: are you sure `activity` is not **nil** while doing `activity.startAnimating()` ?

Comment: have you connected the outlets ?

Comment: Any particular reason functions  `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are outside of your ViewController class?

Comment: Just start loding before request webview

Comment: can you add the crash log?

Comment: @mag_zbc I move webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad inside class, just type here.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I did not set style for it. Do I need to ?

Comment: @Dreams - set your `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` as `Gray` and check once

Comment: I think its an exception breakpoint not crash....try removing All exception breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for load site in web view

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var YahooWebview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let YURL = URL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")
        YahooWebview.delegate = self
        let YURLRequest = URLRequest(url: YURL!)
        YahooWebview.loadRequest(YURLRequest)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        activity.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        activity.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```